# How to check isScrollFinished in ScrollView

Tags: android

Is there any way to find out the scrolling is finished or not Scrollview? On swiping the scrollview its scrolling for some time and then it stop, i wanted to know is there any way to get the end of the scrolling? Please help me

Comment: you can refer to following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738965/android-detect-when-scrollview-has-finished-scrolling-and-bouncing-back

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to find the scoll position in default ScrollView. To achieve the scrollPosition You need to create **custom ScrollView** and override `onScrollChanged()`

Comment: i am using custom ScrollView, But how do i stop scrolling or how do i know the scrolling is Finished?